# get a field value using variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get a field value from table. I am getting the field id but when I am getting the value of that field it is giving error. I have no idea about this. I have goggled it but no example with variable. Can anyone please help me to get the value here please ?! here are my attempts below :

```
    function setTotalAmount(id){
             var rateField = id.replace(".AMOUNT", ".RATE"),
             rateSelector = "'#"+rateField+"'",
             rate = $(rateSelector).val();
             alert(rate)
        }
```

Here are my HTML ::

```
first template >>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function setTotalAmount(id){
        var rateField = id.replace(".AMOUNT", ".RATE"),
                rateSelector = "#"+rateField,
                rate = $(rateSelector).val();
        alert(rate)
    }

    var childCount = ${up_Proc_MasterInstance?.upDirectProcurementDetails?.size()} + 0;
    $('.delButton').live('click', function() {
//find the parent div
        var prnt = $(this).parents(".detail-div");
//find the deleted hidden input
        var delInput = prnt.find("input[id$=deleted]");
        delInput.attr('value', 'true');
//hide the div
        prnt.hide();
    });
    function addChild() {
//debugger;
        var clone = $("#detail_clone").clone();
        var htmlId = 'upDirectProcurementDetails[' + childCount + '].';

        clone.find("input[id$=id]").attr('id', htmlId + 'id').attr('name', htmlId + 'id');
        clone.find("input[id$=deleted]").attr('id', htmlId + 'deleted').attr('name', htmlId + 'deleted');
        clone.find("input[id$=new]").attr('id', htmlId + 'new').attr('name', htmlId + 'new').attr('value', 'true');

        clone.find("input[id$=RATE]").attr('id', htmlId + 'RATE').attr('name', htmlId + 'RATE');
        clone.find("input[id$=AMOUNT]").attr('id', htmlId + 'AMOUNT').attr('name', htmlId + 'AMOUNT');
        clone.find("input[id$=TOTAL_PRICE]").attr('id', htmlId + 'TOTAL_PRICE').attr('name', htmlId + 'TOTAL_PRICE');

        clone.attr('id', 'detail' + childCount);

        $("#detailList").append(clone);
        clone.show();
        childCount++;
    }
</script>
<div class="" style="border: solid 1px;border-radius: 5px">
    <table  style=" border-radius:5px;table-layout: fixed" id="detailList" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        %{--<table id="example" class="dataListTable table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">--}%
        <tr><th>ITEM ID</th><th>ITEM NAME</th><th>ITEM DETAILS</th><th>RATE</th><th>AMOUNT</th><th>TOTAL AMOUNT</th><th width="44px">Action</th></tr>
        <g:render template='detail' model="['result':null,'i':'_clone','hidden':true]"/>
        <g:each var="upDirectProcurementDetails" in="${up_Proc_MasterInstance.upDirectProcurementDetails}" status="i" >
            <g:render template='detail' model="['upDirectProcurementDetails':upDirectProcurementDetails,'i':i]"/>
        </g:each>
    </table>
    <input type="button"  style="border: 2px solid" class="btn btn-info btn-md save" value="Add Detail" onclick="addChild();"/>
</div>
```

Second template where only rows >>

```
 <tr id="detail${i}" name="tr[${i}]" class="detail-div" <g:if test="${hidden}">style="display:none;"</g:if>>
    <g:hiddenField name='upDirectProcurementDetails[${i}].id' value='${upDirectProcurementDetails?.id}'/>
        <g:hiddenField name='upDirectProcurementDetails[${i}].deleted' value='false'/>
        <g:hiddenField name='upDirectProcurementDetails[${i}].new' value="${upDirectProcurementDetails?.id == null?'true':'false'}"/>

<td><g:textField size="13px" name='upDirectProcurementDetails[${i}].RATE' value='${upDirectProcurementDetails?.RATE}' class='detail-number form-control'/></td>
<td><g:textField size="13px" name='upDirectProcurementDetails[${i}].AMOUNT' value='${upDirectProcurementDetails?.AMOUNT}' onblur="setTotalAmount(this.id)" class='detail-txt form-control'/></td>
<td><g:textField size="13px" name='upDirectProcurementDetails[${i}].TOTAL_PRICE' value='${upDirectProcurementDetails?.TOTAL_PRICE}' class='detail-txt form-control' readonly=""/></td>
<td><span style="font-size: 20px;color: #ff0000"  class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash delButton' id='delButton${i}' name='results[${i}].delButton'/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: what is the output of `alert(id)` at the beginning of the function?

Comment: @AminJafari the output of alert(id) is >>  upDirectProcurementDetails[0].AMOUNT

Comment: `upDirectProcurementDetails` is the id, right?

Comment: yes, but index is required also for each row value

Comment: you know that ids must be unique, so the index is not required! if you have more than one element with the same id, your html is not valid and you must change the structure and replace the id with class!

Comment: ok can you provide an example with class

Comment: please share your html code so we can see the structure for further improvements

Comment: Give JS fiddle example for peope to debug issue, else its wild goose chase

Answer (score 0):

Use `rateSelector = "#"+rateField,`

Use `var rateField = id.replace("#AMOUNT", "#RATE"),`

You dont need to wrap it in single Quotes.

Comment: provide here your html also

Comment: id.replace NEEDS both arguments to be ID , u passed class (it uses dot (.))

Comment: Give JS fiddle example for peope to debug issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code. I think this may help you.

```
function setTotalAmount(){
var rateField = $('#AMOUNT').attr('id','RATE');
rate = $(rateField).val();
alert(rate)
}
setTotalAmount();
```

Comment: Please provide Fiddle link then only it can be easy to find the issue.